# printing binary tree in php based website

Tags: php, jquery

I'm making a php+mysql based website and i need to draw a binary tree. Through googling i came to know that jquery is good for this. actually i am completelly unaware of jquery. so should i go for "jquery"? Any suggestion..

Comment: What do you mean by "draw"? Do you want to output html, ascii art or an image? What does mysql have to do with this?

Comment: The question is very vague. The objective is unclear. The contraints are not stated. You seem to think jquery is a solution but the only tag currently on your question is PHP

Comment: data that is to be printed as nodes of tree are to be taken from database my friend..!

Comment: Just give it a try! http://plugins.jquery.com/project/BinaryTree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you want, but there is a plugin to draw binary trees using JQuery:

http://frank-mich.com/jQuery/

This is the example:

```
var myTree;
$(function(){
    myTree = $("#treeDiv").btree()[0];   // create the tree and associated to '#treeDiv'
});

function redraw(){
    myTree.clear();     // remove the tree
    myTree = $("#treeDiv").btree({
        branchColor: $("#color").val(),     // Take the color from '#color' input
        branchStroke: $("#stroke").val(),     // Take the branch stroke from '#stroke' input
        hSpace: $("#hSpace").val(),         // Take the horizontal space from '#hSpace' input
        vSpace: $("#vSpace").val(),         // Take the vertical space from '#vSpace' input
        borderWidth: $("#border").val(),     // Take the width border from '#border' input
        horizontal: $("#horizontal").attr('checked'),    // Take the orientation from '#horizontal' input
        flip: $("#flip").attr('checked')       // Do you want to flip the tree? from '#flip' input
    })[0];
}
```

He created some inputs and he was reading the values to build the tree from their. You can pass the values what you want directly.

On the 'Usage' section you can find more information about how to test this plugin.

Comment: yup its satisfying all what i need. thanks. so now m gona start learning jquery.

Comment: Just a tip: right-click on the webpage that I shared you before > View source code. Now you can see the source code of the example showed at "Binary tree in action" section. Your welcome :)

Comment: when m using copied source of link you gave, its not displaying binary tree. please can you give me code by removing unnecessary stuffs, so that it only draws binary tree..(the box only is getting displayed not the tree)

Comment: @fran: BUt problem is that the main box is getting displayed but boxes(nodes) within are getting displayed horizontally and not as  tree.

Comment: @fran: if i am deleting box the tree is not getting displayed. any suggestion..?

Comment: Which box are you try to remove? To draw the tree like a "real tree", use vertical orientation and flip set to 'true'.

Comment: i want horizontal orientation with flip true. say for eg if i m removing box 15 then whole structure gets collapsed!